# What is the use of the combination of chunk_split() and base64_encode()

Tags: php, base64

I am working on sending attachment with php mail .When google'd on it I found that a combination of `chunk_split()` and `base64_encode()` is using in mail headers.

Here `base64_encode($data)` function encodes the given data into a encoded string. But what is the use of `chunk_split()` along with `base64_enocde()` as this `chunk_split` needs three parameters(string which is about to chink,chunk length and the parameter that is to be added at the end of the chunk), but we are providing only one parameter.

I think `chunk_split()` returns the same string when we provide only one paramter(I mean `chuck_split("mystr") == "mystr"`). Then what is the use of `chunk_split(base64_encode("mystr"));` ?

Comment: [chunk_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php) only returns the same string if the length of the string ___is less than___ __76 bytes__ (or the specified length if you pass a length argument). RFC 2045 specifies a maximum length of 76 bytes (`Quoted-Printable encoding. If you read the PHP docs for [chunk_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php), it explains this
          REQUIRES that encoded lines be no more than 76
          characters long.` for quoted printable content

Comment: What in the documentation of the `chunk_split()` function is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

`base64_encode()` function fails for larger size files, in my case for images greater than 7 mb.

`Chunk_split` Can be used to split a string into smaller chunks which is useful for e.g. converting `base64_encode()` output to match `RFC 2045` semantics.

It inserts end (defaults to `\r\n`) every chunklen characters (defaults to 76). It returns the new string leaving the original string untouched.
So there combination allows to match the string that confirms with `RFC` semantics which is used in sending data content other than text may be images or attachment in mails using mime protocol.